# can I use a dynamic entity context in my method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, entity-framework-5, dynamic-linq

I have a method for gridview sorting and paging which I am trying to make reusable for generic types but I am struggling to figure out how to make the entity context (MyContext) and table (tblReports) dynamic variables - can anyone help me out please?

```
protected void PopulateGridView<T>(GridView grid)
{
    string columnToSortBy = (string)(ViewState["gridview_sortbycolumn"] ?? string.Empty);
    SortDirection sortDirection = (SortDirection)(ViewState["gridview_sortdirection"] ?? SortDirection.Descending);
    int pageIndex = (int)(ViewState["gridview_pageindex"] ?? 0);
    int pageSize = grid.PageCount;

    using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
    {
        if (columnToSortBy != string.Empty)
        {
            var query = db.tblReports.OrderBy(columnToSortBy + " " + sortDirection).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize);
            grid.DataSource = query.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            string defaultColumn = string.Empty;

            foreach (var field in typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                defaultColumn = field.Name.Remove(field.Name.IndexOf(">")).Replace("<", string.Empty);
                break;
            }

            var query = db.tblReports.OrderBy(defaultColumn).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize);
            grid.DataSource = query.ToList();
        }

        grid.PageIndex = pageIndex;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong? What does the example code do (or not).

Comment: thanks for the reply, I currently have to declare a specific entity context (MyContext) and refer to a specific entity table (tblReport) - I'd like to be able to abstract them outside of the method so it can become generic and handle any gridview without being tied to specific config.

Comment: Can't you pass the tblReports as parameter? and use `typeof(tableparameter)` instead of `typeof(T)`. Makes: `PopulateGridView(grid, db.tableReports);` Look for the tblReports base class as parameter type.

Comment: I was hoping I could use something like context.typeof(T) in my queries but it doesn't like that syntax.  I'd rather not pass tblReports as a parameter as I've already solved that issue by making the method accept generic types

Comment: The problem of passing it as a generic, that there isn't an instance, so you still need to pass an instance somewhere. And if you pass an instance, you can use a `GetType()` to get it's type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by passing the entity table as a parameter as suggested by @Jeroen and casting the linq query result to generic type.

Here is the final code for anyone who is interested :

```
protected void PopulateGridView<T>(GridView grid, DbSet entityTable)
{
    string columnToSortBy = (string)(ViewState["gridview_sortbycolumn"] ?? string.Empty);
    SortDirection sortDirection = (SortDirection)(ViewState["gridview_sortdirection"] ?? SortDirection.Descending);
    int pageIndex = (int)(ViewState["gridview_pageindex"] ?? 0);

    if (columnToSortBy != string.Empty)
    {
        grid.DataSource = entityTable.OrderBy(columnToSortBy + " " + sortDirection).Cast<T>().ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        // use linq reflection to get the first entity field name to sort by
        string defaultColumn = string.Empty;

        foreach (var field in typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            defaultColumn = field.Name.Remove(field.Name.IndexOf(">")).Replace("<", string.Empty);
            break;
        }

        grid.DataSource = entityTable.OrderBy(defaultColumn).Cast<T>().ToList();
    }

    grid.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```